# 2 different php scripts 2 different logins. How can I make one login?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have 2 PHP scripts, each have their own register and login forms. I want to be able to take the user information from one and use it on the other so that my members do not have to register or login on the second PHP script. Below is the login, register and logout functions for both scripts

This is PHP script #1 where I already have members:

```html
#check login from login form
 public function login()

 {

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('useremail','Email','required|xss_clean');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|xss_clean');

  

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)

  {

   $this->trylogin(); 

  }

  else

  {

   $this->load->model('auth_model');

   $query = $this->auth_model->check_login($this->input->post('useremail'),$this->input->post('password'),'result');



   if($query->num_rows()>0)

   {    

    $row = $query->row();

    if($row->banned==1)

    {

     $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.

              '<button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">Ã—</button>'.

              '<strong>'.lang_key('user_banned').'</strong>'.

          '</div>';

     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);       

     redirect(site_url('account/trylogin'));

    }
    else if($row->confirmed!=1)

    {

     $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.

              '<button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">Ã—</button>'.

              '<strong>'.lang_key('account_not_confirmed').'</strong>'.

          '</div>';

     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);       

     redirect(site_url('account/trylogin'));

    }

    else

    {

     if(is_admin($row->user_name,$row->user_type))
      create_log($row->user_name);
     
     $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$row->id);

     $this->session->set_userdata('user_name',$row->user_name);

     $this->session->set_userdata('user_type',$row->user_type);

     $this->session->set_userdata('user_email',$this->input->post('useremail'));

     

     if($this->session->userdata('req_url')!='')

     {

      $req_url = $this->session->userdata('req_url');

      $this->session->set_userdata('req_url','');

      redirect($req_url);

     }

     redirect(site_url());     

    }

   }

   else

   {    

    $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.

             '<button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">Ã—</button>'.

             '<strong>'.lang_key('email_or_password_not_mathed').'</strong>'.

         '</div>';

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);       

    redirect(site_url('account/trylogin'));

   }

  }



 }


 #logout a user
 public function logout()

 {

  $this->session->sess_destroy();

  redirect(site_url());

 }

 #loads signup view
 public function signup()
 {
  if(is_loggedin())
  {
   redirect(base_url());
  }

  if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_signup','Yes')=='No')
  {
   redirect(site_url());
  }

  $data['content']  = load_view('register_view','',TRUE);
        $data['alias']     = 'signup';
        load_template($data,$this->active_theme);
 }

    public function takepackage()
    {
  if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_signup','Yes')=='No')
  {
   redirect(site_url());
  }


  $this->form_validation->set_rules('package_id', 'Package id', 'required');  
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->signup(); 
  }
  else
  {
   $package_id = $this->input->post('package_id');
   $this->session->set_userdata('package_id',$package_id);
   if($this->session->userdata('from')=='facebook')
   {
    $this->session->set_userdata('from','signup');
    redirect(site_url('account/fbauth'));
   }
   else
    redirect(site_url('account/signupform'));
  }
    }

    public function signupform()
    {
  if(is_loggedin())
  {
   redirect(base_url());
  }

  if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_signup','Yes')=='No')
  {
   redirect(site_url());
  }


     if($this->session->userdata('package_id')=='')
     {
      if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_pricing','Yes')=='Yes')
       redirect(site_url('account/signup'));
      else
       $value = array();
     }
     else
     {
      $this->load->model('admin/package_model');
   $value['package']  = $this->package_model->get_package_by_id($this->session->userdata('package_id'));
     }


        $data['content']  = load_view('register_view',$value,TRUE);
        $data['alias']     = 'signup';
        load_template($data,$this->active_theme);
    }

 #controls different signup method routing
 function newaccount($type='',$user_type='business')
 {
  if(is_loggedin())
  {
   redirect(base_url());
  }

  if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_signup','Yes')=='No')
  {
   redirect(site_url());
  }

  if($user_type=='business')
  $this->session->set_userdata('signup_user_type',2);
  else
  $this->session->set_userdata('signup_user_type',3);

  if($type=='fb')
   redirect(site_url('account/fbauth'));

  else if($type=='google_plus')
  {
   redirect(site_url('account/google_plus_auth'));
  }
 }


 #signup form submits to this function
 function register()
 {
  if(is_loggedin())
  {
   redirect(base_url());
  }
  
  if(get_settings('business_settings','enable_signup','Yes')=='No')
  {
   redirect(site_url());
  }

  $user_type = $this->input->post('user_type');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', lang_key('first_name'),   'required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', lang_key('last_name'),   'required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender',  lang_key('gender'),    'required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username',  lang_key('username'),   'required|callback_username_check|xss_clean');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name',lang_key('company_name'),  'xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone',lang_key('phone'),  'xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('useremail', lang_key('user_email'),   'required|valid_email|xss_clean|callback_useremail_check');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password',  lang_key('password'),   'required|matches[repassword]|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('repassword', lang_key('confirm_password'),    'required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms_conditon',lang_key('terms_and_condition'),'xss_clean|callback_terms_check');
  $enable_pricing = get_settings('business_settings','enable_pricing','Yes');
  

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->signup(); 
  }
  else
  {

   $this->load->library('encrypt');

   $userdata['user_type'] = 2;//2 = users

   $userdata['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
   $userdata['last_name']  = $this->input->post('last_name');
   $userdata['gender']  = $this->input->post('gender');   
   $userdata['user_name']  = $this->input->post('username');
   $userdata['user_email'] = $this->input->post('useremail');
   $userdata['password']  = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password'));
   $userdata['confirmation_key']  = uniqid();
   $userdata['confirmed']  = 0;
   $userdata['status']  = 1;

   $this->load->model('user/user_model');
   $user_id = $this->user_model->insert_user_data($userdata);
   
   add_user_meta($user_id,'company_name',$this->input->post('company_name'));
            add_user_meta($user_id,'phone',$this->input->post('phone'));
   
   $this->send_confirmation_email($userdata); 
   $this->load->config('business_directory');
   if($this->config->item('send_admin_email_user_signup')=='Yes')
   $this->send_admin_notification_email();   
   redirect(site_url('account/success'));    
  }
 }
```

This is PHP script #2 where I have no members and want to have PHP script #1 members visit without having to register or login:

```html
/* USER LOGIN */

public static function is_logged() {

global $db;

if( !isset( $_COOKIE['user-session'] ) ) {

    return false;

} else {

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();

    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT user FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "sessions WHERE session = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $_COOKIE['user-session'] );
    $stmt->bind_result( $id );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();

if( !empty( $id ) ) {

    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT name, email, avatar, points, credits, ipaddr, privileges, erole, subscriber, last_login, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "stores WHERE user = u.id), visits, valid, ban, date FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users u WHERE id = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );
    $stmt->bind_result( $name, $email, $avatar, $points, $credits, $ip, $privileges, $erole, $subscriber, $last_login, $stores, $visits, $valid, $ban, $date );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();

    // update action
    $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET points = IF(last_action < DATE(NOW()), points + ?, points), last_action = NOW() WHERE id = ?" );
    $daily_points = \query\main::get_option( 'u_points_davisit' );
    $stmt->bind_param( "ii", $daily_points, $id );
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    return (object) array( 'ID' => $id, 'Name' => esc_html( $name ), 'Email' => esc_html( $email ), 'Avatar' => esc_html( $avatar ), 'Points' => $points, 'Credits' => $credits, 'IP' => esc_html( $ip ), 'Privileges' => $privileges, 'Erole' => @unserialize( $erole ), 'Last_login' => $last_login, 'Stores' => $stores, 'Visits' => $visits, 'Date' => $date, 'is_subscribed' => $subscriber, 'is_confirmed' => $valid, 'is_banned' => ( strtotime( $ban ) > time() ? true : false ), 'is_subadmin' => ( $privileges >= 1 ? true : false ), 'is_admin' => ( $privileges > 1 ? true : false ) );

} else {

    $stmt->close();

    return false;

}

}

}

/* BANNED */

public static function banned( $type = '', $IP = '' ) {

global $db;

switch( $type ) {

    case 'registration':
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "banned WHERE ipaddr = ? AND registration = 1" );
        $userip = empty( $IP ) ? \site\utils::getIP() : $IP;
        $stmt->bind_param( "s", $userip );
        $stmt->bind_result( $count );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        if( $count > 0 ) return true;
        return false;
    break;

    case 'login':
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "banned WHERE ipaddr = ? AND login = 1" );
        $userip = empty( $IP ) ? \site\utils::getIP() : $IP;
        $stmt->bind_param( "s", $userip );
        $stmt->bind_result( $count );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        if( $count > 0 ) return true;
        return false;
    break;

    default:
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare( "SELECT id, redirect_to FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "banned WHERE ipaddr = ? AND site = 1 AND ( expiration = 0 OR ( expiration = 1 AND expiration_date > NOW() ) )" );
        $userip = empty( $IP ) ? \site\utils::getIP() : $IP;
        $stmt->bind_param( "s", $userip );
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $new_location );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        if( !empty( $id ) ) return $new_location;
        return false;
    break;

}

    return false;

}

/* USER LOGOUT */

public static function logout() {

global $db;

if( !isset( $_COOKIE['user-session'] ) ) {

    return false;

} else {

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();

    $stmt->prepare( "DELETE FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "sessions WHERE session = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $_COOKIE['user-session'] );
    $execute = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if( $execute ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

}

/* USER LOGIN */

public static function login( $post, $privileges = 0 ) {

global $db;

$session = '';

if( self::banned( 'login' ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_banned', "Sorry, but this action isn't permitted for you at this time." ) );
} else {

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT id, password, ban FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE email = ? AND privileges >= ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "si", $post['username'], $privileges );
    $stmt->bind_result( $id, $password, $ban );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();

    if( empty( $id ) ) {

    // user does not even exist

    throw new \Exception( t( 'login_invalid', "Login details are invalid." ) );

    } else if( strtotime( $ban ) > time() ) {

    // banned user

    throw new \Exception( t( 'login_banaccount', "Your account it's banned for security reasons, often for failed login attempts. Please try later." ) );

    } else if( (string)$password !== (string) md5( $post['password'] ) ) {

    // wrong password

    $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET fail_attempts = IF(fail_attempts >= " . BAN_AFTER_ATTEMPTS . ", 1, fail_attempts + 1), ban = IF(fail_attempts >= " . BAN_AFTER_ATTEMPTS . ", DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . BAN_AFTER_FAIL . " MINUTE), ban) WHERE email = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $post['username'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    throw new \Exception( t( 'login_invalid', "Login details are invalid." ) );

    } else {

    $session = md5( \site\utils::str_random(15) );

    // delete old sessions
    $stmt->prepare( "DELETE FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "sessions WHERE user = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );
    $stmt->execute();

    // insert new session
    $stmt->prepare( "INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "sessions SET user = ?, session = ?, expiration = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . ( isset( $post['keep_logged'] ) ? DEF_USER_SESSION_KL : DEF_USER_SESSION ) . " MINUTE), date = NOW()" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "is", $id, $session );

    if( !$stmt->execute() ) {

    $stmt->close();
    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

    } else {

    $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET ipaddr = ?, last_login = NOW(), visits = visits + 1, fail_attempts = 0 WHERE id = ?" );

    $userip = \site\utils::getIP();

    $stmt->bind_param( "si", $userip, $id );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    }

    }

}

    return $session;

}

/* USER REGISTER */

public static function register( $post ) {

global $db;

$session = '';

$max_acc = (int) \query\main::get_option( 'accounts_per_ip' );

if( $max_acc !== 0 && (int) \query\main::users( array( 'ip' => \site\utils::getIP() ) ) >= $max_acc ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) ); // administrator don't allow that manny accounts
} else if( self::banned( 'registration' ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_banned', "Sorry, but this action isn't permitted for you at this time." ) );
} else if( !isset( $post['email'] ) || !filter_var( $post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_usevalide', "Please use a valid email address." ) );
} else if( !isset( $post['username'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_complete_name', "Please fill the name." ) );
} else if( !preg_match( '/(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,25}$)/', $post['username'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_invalid_name', "The name should not contain special characters, not less than 3 and no more than 25 characters." ) );
} else if( !isset( $post['password'] ) || !isset( $post['password2'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_paswdreq', "Both passwords are required." ) );
} else if( !preg_match( '/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,40}$)/', $post['password'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_invalid_paswd', "Password should not contain special characters, not less than 5 and no more than 40 characters." ) );
} else if( $post['password'] != $post['password2'] ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_passwdnm', "Passwords do not match!" ) );
} else {

    if( !$session = self::insert_user( $post ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_accexists', "This email address already exists." ) );
    }

    return $session;

    }

}

/* INSERT USER */

public static function insert_user( $info = array(), $autologin = false, $autovalid = false ) {

    /*
        ** ATTENTION
        If $autologin is set to true, login don't require the password !
    */

    global $db;

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();

    $stmt->prepare( "INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users (name, email, password, points, ipaddr, last_action, valid, refid, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, NOW())" );

    $passwd = isset( $info['password'] ) ? md5( $info['password'] ) : md5( \site\utils::str_random(15) );
    $points = (int) \query\main::get_option( 'u_def_points' );
    $IPaddr = \site\utils::getIP();
    $valid = (int) ( $autovalid ? 1 : (boolean) \query\main::get_option( 'u_confirm_req' ) );
    $refid = isset( $_COOKIE['referrer'] ) ? (int) $_COOKIE['referrer'] : 0;

    $stmt->bind_param( "sssssii", $info['username'], $info['email'], $passwd, $points, $IPaddr, $valid, $refid );
    $execute = $stmt->execute();

    if( !$execute && !$autologin ) {

        return false;

    } else {

    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT id FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE email = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $info['email'] );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result( $id );
    $stmt->fetch();

    $session = md5( \site\utils::str_random(15) );

    $stmt->prepare( "INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "sessions SET user = ?, session = ?, expiration = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . DEF_USER_SESSION . " MINUTE), date = NOW()" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "is", $id, $session );
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET last_login = NOW(), visits = 1 WHERE id = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );
    $stmt->execute();

    if( !$valid ) {

    $cofirm_session = md5( \site\utils::str_random(15) );
    if( \user\mail_sessions::insert( 'confirmation', array( 'user' => $id, 'session' => $cofirm_session ) ) )
        \site\mail::send( $info['email'], t( 'email_acc_title', "Activate account" ) . ' - ' . \query\main::get_option( 'sitename' ), array( 'template' => 'account_confirmation' ), array( 'hello_name' => sprintf( t( 'email_text_hello', "Hello %s" ), $info['username'] ), 'confirmation_main_text' => t( 'email_acc_maintext', "Click on the link bellow to confirm your account." ), 'confirmation_button' => t( 'email_acc_button', "Activate account!" ), 'link' => \site\utils::update_uri( $GLOBALS['siteURL'] . 'verify.php', array( 'user' => $id, 'token' => $cofirm_session ) ) ) );

    } else if( $valid && $refid !== 0 ) {

    // add points to user who referred the new user
    \user\update::add_points( $refid, \query\main::get_option( 'u_points_refer' ) );

    }

    $stmt->close();

    return $session;

    }

}

/* USER RECOVERY PASSWORD */

public static function recovery_password( $post, $path = '', $privileges = 0 ) {

global $db;

if( !isset( $post['email'] ) || !filter_var( $post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'register_usevalide', "Please use a valid email address." ) );
} else {

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT id FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE email = ? AND privileges >= ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "si", $post['email'], $privileges );
    $stmt->bind_result( $user );
    $execute = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    if( !$execute || empty( $user ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'fp_unkwacc', "Sorry, we couldn't find this account in our database." ) );
    } else {

    $session = md5( \site\utils::str_random(15) );

    if( \user\mail_sessions::insert( 'password_recovery', array( 'user' => $user, 'session' => $session ) ) ) {

        // send email
        if( \site\mail::send( $post['email'], t( 'email_reset_title', "Reset your password" ) . ' - ' . \query\main::get_option( 'sitename' ), array( 'template' => 'password_reset', 'path' => $path ), array( 'reset_main_text' => t( 'email_reset_maintext', "Click on the link bellow to reset your password." ), 'reset_button' => t( 'email_reset_button', "Reset password!" ), 'link' => \site\utils::update_uri( '', array( 'uid' => $user, 'session' => $session ) ) ) ) )

        return true;

    }

    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

    }

    }

}

/* RESET PASSWORD */

public static function reset_password( $id, $post ) {

    global $db;

    if( !isset( $post['password1'] ) || !preg_match( '/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,40}$)/', $post['password1'] ) ) {
        throw new \Exception( t( 'reset_pwd_wrong_np', "Password should not contain special characters, not less than 5 and no more than 40 characters." ) );
    } else if( !isset( $post['password1'] ) || !isset( $post['password2'] ) || $post['password1'] != $post['password2'] ) {
        throw new \Exception( t( 'reset_pwd_pwddm', "Passwords do not match!" ) );
    } else {

        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?" );

        $password = md5( $post['password1'] );

        $stmt->bind_param( "si", $password, $id );
        $execute = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if( !$execute ) throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

    }

}

/* CHANGE PASSWORD */

public static function change_password( $id, $post ) {

    global $db;

    if( !isset( $post['new'] ) || !preg_match( '/(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{5,40}$)/', $post['new'] ) ) {
        throw new \Exception( t( 'change_pwd_wrong_np', "Password should not contain special characters, not less than 5 and no more than 40 characters." ) );
    } else if( !isset( $post['new'] ) || !isset( $post['new2'] ) || $post['new'] != $post['new2'] ) {
        throw new \Exception( t( 'change_pwd_pwddm', "Passwords do not match!" ) );
    } else {

        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare( "SELECT password FROM " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = ?" );
        $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );
        $stmt->bind_result( $password );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();

        if( md5( $post['old'] ) == $password ) {

        $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?" );

        $new = md5( $post['new'] );

        $stmt->bind_param( "si", $new, $id );
        $execute = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if( $execute ) {

            return true;

        } else throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

        } else {

            $stmt->close();

            throw new \Exception( t( 'change_pwd_wrongpwd', "Your current password it's wrong!" ) );

        }

    }

}

/* EDIT PROFILE */

public static function edit_profile( $id, $post ) {

global $db;

if( !isset( $post['username'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'profile_complete_name', "Please fill the name." ) );
} else if( !preg_match( '/(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,25}$)/', $post['username'] ) ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'profile_invalid_name', "The name should not contain special characters, not less than 3 and no more than 25 characters." ) );
} else {

    $avatar = \site\images::upload( $_FILES['edit_profile_form_avatar'], 'avatar_', array( 'max_size' => 1024, 'max_width' => 600, 'max_height' => 600, 'current' => $GLOBALS['me']->Avatar ) );

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET name = ?, avatar = ?, subscriber = ? WHERE id = ?" );

    $subscriber = ( isset( $post['subscriber'] ) ? 1 : 0 );

    $stmt->bind_param( "ssii", $post['username'], $avatar, $subscriber, $id );
    $execute = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if( $execute ) {

    return (object) array( 'avatar' => $avatar );

    } else {

    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

    }

}

}

/* WRITE REVIEW */

public static function write_review( $id, $user, $post ) {

global $db;

if( !( $allow = (int) \query\main::get_option( 'allow_reviews' ) ) || !isset( $post['stars'] ) || !in_array( $post['stars'], array( 1,2,3,4,5 ) )    ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) ); // this error can appear only when the user try to modify post data OR administrator don't allow new reviews
} else if( $allow === 2 && !$GLOBALS['me']->is_confirmed ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'review_write_notv', "Your account isn't confirmed, you can't write reviews." ) );
} else if( !isset( $post['text'] ) || trim( $post['text'] ) == '' ) {
    throw new \Exception( t( 'review_write_text', "Please fill a message." ) );
} else {

    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare( "INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "reviews (user, store, text, stars, valid, lastupdate_by, lastupdate, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())" );

    $valid = (boolean) \query\main::get_option( 'review_validate' );

    $stmt->bind_param( "iisiii", $user, $id, $post['text'], $post['stars'], $valid, $user );
    $execute = $stmt->execute();

    if( $execute ) {

        if( ( $ppr = \query\main::get_option( 'u_points_review' ) ) > 0 ) {

        $stmt->prepare( "UPDATE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users SET points = points + ? WHERE id = ?" );
        $stmt->bind_param( "ii", $ppr, $user );
        $stmt->execute();

        }

        $stmt->close();

        return true;

    } else {

        throw new \Exception( t( 'msg_error', "Error!" ) );

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Just use the same user details from the what ever table you're using with the first login or use a join to select user details from the table bound with the script 1 if they're in the same DB.

Comment: Hi Sand, Thanks for your answer. It may be easy to do for someone that knows, but I am kind of new to this, can you please provide me an example that I can use as reference?

Comment: I do have both scripts in the same database, the php script #1 has table dbc_users with fields 
id
user_type
first_name
last_name
gender
profile_photo
user_name
user_email
password
remember_me_key
recovery_key
confirmation_key
confirmed
confirmed_date
status
banned
banned_date
banned_till

Comment: and php script #2 has table users with fields 

id
name
email
password
avatar
points
credits
ipaddr
privileges
erole
subscriber
last_login
last_action
visits
fail_attempts
valid
ban
refid
extra
date

Comment: Sorry for tanking this long to comment was busy in real life. I don't know if you have solved this but from what you're stating in comments I understand you're 2 scripts kind of talk to 2 tables. What you have to do is when you're creating the user you have to pass that users user ID which get added to your 1st table to a column in your 2nd table which will allow you to look up both tables using that ID. This also gives you a chance not replicate the same data on 2 table.

Comment: thanks, I will try this tomorrow and report back to you.